# Windows 8.1 upgraded from Windows 7 can't recognize DVD/Blu-ray media

Tags: dvd, windows-8.1, blu-ray

I have a Vaio F series laptop with a Pioneer Blu-ray internal drive running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. After upgrading to Windows 8.1 the Blu-ray drive cannot recognize any DVD or Blu-ray media. On clicking on the D: drive in Windows Explorer this message is flashed: `Format Disc/ You do not have sufficient rights to perform this operation`.

I tried unsuccessfully with different players like WinDVD Pro 11, PowerDVD 13 and VLC 2.1. All are saying: `No DVD/Media in drive`. My internal drive is Pioneer BD RW BDR TD03. I also tried to update the firmware from Device Manager, but it's saying: `Your driver is up to date`. Do I have to purchase an external Blu-ray RW for playing the DVD/Blu-Ray discs or revert back to Windows 7?

Comment: Have you tride iDeer Blu-ray Player? Anyway I don't think it's a good idea to revert back to Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 and 8.1 no longer have built in [support](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2403983,00.asp) for DVD or BluRay movies.  Support requires licensing, and they dropped it to keep costs down.

For those who are still partial to DVDs, however, Windows 8 will offer the option to purchase Windows Media Center with DVD playback functionality via an "Add Features to Windows 8" menu.

Comment: What about Blu-Ray discs? I own the Media Center Pack. Besides, it was free to those who obtained Windows 8 during the special pricing (if you obtained it at the right time).

Comment: I dont think it includes Blu-Ray